# How to use Enumerable Methods

Tags: c#, enumeration

I have looked around for some good explanations of these enumerable methods but cant seem to find one that explains it properly.

I have been using a few of them like select,skip,orderby and sort but I don't know how they actually work

For example

```
string[] RandomNames = names.OrderBy(x => rnd.Next()).ToArray();
```

or

```
string[] SelectedNames = names.Select(i => i.ToString()).ToArray()
```

So there are a few things that I am unclear of:

- So what does the => actually do
- How would a group by work and what would it be used for.

A brief explanation would be appreciated but an in depth explanation is what I am looking for.

Comment: `=>` means lamda function, in the sample above a function which takes one argument (`x`) and returns `rnd.Next()` value

Comment: You might want to read this from "Documentation" : http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/c%23/68/linq-queries/4735/basics#t=201607251259571763764

Comment: Think of the lambda argument (x) as an individual item inside the array for those functions

Comment: Thank you Kinetic your answer is exactly what i am looking for

Comment: This link https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397906.aspx may be helpful

Comment: That is a dozen questions in one...

Comment: Yes it is Patrick... I have/had a lot of confusion on this subject. the link Kinetic provided is extremely helpfull

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`=>` is lambda expression.

What is lambda expression and why is so useful? Let's consider example:
You have list of random `integers` and you want to choose only divided by 2. In normal way it will look like that:

```
 public bool IsDevidedByTwo(int number)
 {
    if(number % 2 == 0)
       return true;
    return false ;
 }

List<int> DevidedByTwoList = new List<int>;

foreach(var number in RandomIntsList)
{
   if(IsdevidedByTwo(number)) DevidedByTwoList.Add(number);
}
```

It easy an clear but takes lot of space so you can't understand it immediatly especially when function `IsDevidedByTwo()` will be in diffrent file. 
How it will be look like when you use lamba expression and LINQ:

```
List<int> DevidedByTwoList = RandomIntsList.Where(number => number % 2 == 0).ToList();
```

One line instead of 12.

`number => number % 2==0` is lambda expression. It's check if number is devided by 2. It works exacly like `IsDevidedByTwo` function but you don't need to name it.

`.Where()` is LINQ method witch can filter for example list and choose only elements fulfill condition in brackets.

If you want to learn more read something about [LINQ](http://www.tutorialsteacher.com/linq/linq-tutorials) and [lambda expresions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397687.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

A lambda expression is an anonymous function and it is mostly used to create delegates in LINQ. Simply put, it's a method without a declaration, i.e., access modifier, return value declaration, and name.

It Reduces typing. No need to specify the name of the function, its return type, and its access modifier.When reading the code, you don't need to look elsewhere for the method's definition.

Here is a very good article with examples and explanations.

[geekswithblogs](http://geekswithblogs.net/Martinez/archive/2009/10/29/linq-groupby-method-tutorial.aspx)

Comment: The link is (effectively) broken. It redirects to *[Geekswithblogs.net, the End of an Era](http://julian.farm/geekswithblogs/?url=/mtreadwell/archive/2004/06/06/6123.aspx)*.